# A silly question about packages organization!

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Inside a package there is initially the two files CMakeList.txt and package.xml and the folder **src**. From the tutorials, I understood that the scripts belonging to a package should be placed in its scr folder. However, while studying ROS I found many packages that had thier scripts placed in a user created folder called **scripts**. Taking into account the said, my question is: Why someones creates a new folder called **script** instead to use the already existing one called **scr**. Is this a ROS good practices or just a user preference? If it is a good practice, for what I should use the folder **script** and for what should I use the folder **src**.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227430/a-silly-question-about-packages-organization!!!/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) on 2016-02-24**:
Do you have an example of such a package?

**Comment by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on 2016-02-24**:
For example: https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/tree/master/chapter_3_codes/seven_dof_arm_gazebo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_make looks inside your src directory. However, my understanding is that those scripts are in Python and don't need to go through the gcc compiler. Thus, it doesn't need to compile them into executables. Generally you'd put them in src if they were C++ files. I'm not exactly sure what "good practices" are in this scenario but that's why it's ok to put them in scripts instead of src.

---

Originally posted by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) with karma: 194 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is mostly relevant for python packages. The usual practice is to put scripts that can be executed by users in the scripts directory and put source files (also .py) that these scripts use in the src directory.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to complement @alee answer, the best practice (up to my knowledge) is:

- Scripts should go in a `scripts` folder.
- Python code (classes, etc) which are not scripts should go into `src/<pkg_name>/`. Then, in your scripts (or python code) which are not necessarily in the same package, you can import using `from <pkg_name> import foo`.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8